# Change binding value with custom binding in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a custom binding I am using to truncate a description in an observable array. I am just wondering the best way to go about changing the text that is returned to the binding.

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.summarize = { 
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^[^.]+/);
            var summarized = pattern.exec(context.description());
            //How do I set the text to the summarized value?
        }
    }
```

The broad description is used elsewhere on the page. This truncated version is used in the sidebar. Open to suggestions about a better way to go about this but this seemed like the best way to me.

The viewModel is generated from a JSON file via the mapping plugin or I would just add in a truncated version directly in the viewmodel.

Thanks for taking a look at things.

Comment: Okay. So after searching around in the debug code for Knockout.js I came across the default text binding and just used that as a template. I'll post up the binding in a second as well as the way I am using it.

Comment: Joel, am I understanding it right that you found a solution to your own question? If so, please post that as an answer here and mark as answer. That way your question benefits the KnockoutJS community, and your question no longer shows up as unanswered.

Comment: You got it Judah. I went to initially answer it but there was a time restriction on answering your own question and I got caught up in the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I did. It was simple once I looked at the source of the knockout Library. I would highly recommend digging around in the library code. It is invaluable for learning.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.summarize = { 
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[^.]+/);
    var summarized = pattern.exec(context.description());
    typeof element.innerText == "string" ? element.innerText = summarized
                                         : element.textContent = summarized;
    }
}
```

To use it in a template you would simply:

```
<p data-bind='summarize: description'></p>
```

Where description would be an observable.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer your own question. The KO community thanks you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are associating your custom binding with the description in your binding statement `data-bind='summarize: description'`, so you can use the `valueAccessor` parameter for greater flexibility.

I went a step further and used the `ko.unwrap` function so your custom binding can handle non-observable values as well:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.summarize = { 
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[^.]+/);
    var summarized = pattern.exec(ko.unwrap( valueAccessor() ) );
    typeof element.innerText == "string" ? element.innerText = summarized
                                         : element.textContent = summarized;
    }
}
```